# Upper Hemicontinuity getting continuously larger

Tags: real-analysis

I am not being able to understand why, in the following two figures, the left one is upper-hemicontinuous but the right one is not. Also, I don't think I get what it means by the correspondence getting discontinuously larger. In the figure, since the range of co-domain reduces at a certain positive point in x where it discontinues, shouldn't it be "discontinuously smaller"? Am I missing something? Thanks so much!

[image]

Comment: @Aryadeva Please click the link "Image" above for the image as the website said I cannot embed picture because I don't have 10 rep points yet.

Comment: Great, thanks so much, @Aryadeva

Comment: You're welcome and now you have enough reputation to upload pictures on your own.